# How to fit map to full screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My Openlayer map doesn't want to fit to full screen automatically. Any settings don't help to deal with this. What can be issue with? Thank you in advance

[image]

**ol-map.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./map-style.css";

import {
  Map,
  layer,
  Layers
} from "react-openlayers";

class OLMap extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Map">
        <Map view={{
          center: [50.62202375, 26.24943584],
          zoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 11,
          minZoom: 1
        }}>
          <Layers>
            <layer.Tile />
          </Layers>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OLMap;
```

**map-style.css**

```
.Map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to leave an upvote to your question. apologize. hope this motivates you to keep going on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actully the main issue comes from your CSS styles, you should change your `map-style.css` content to the below codes:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#root { /* the root element of ReactJS injection */
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Map {
  border: 2px solid red; /* just to show your wrapper */
  flex: 1;
}

.openlayers-map {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

For more information and codes you can see the sample on my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-bweo0) example.

Comment: now this is what actually I see now after .css file modification
https://ibb.co/861ggYN

Comment: @RobertGurjiev, why you send a picture for me? you should upload a reproduction of your issue to [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/) or somewhere else. How I can help you with a simple screenshot? Especially, without knowing your HTML and parent wrapper?

Comment: Dear @RobertGurjiev, please see [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-bweo0). I modified it just now.

Comment: Dear @AmerllicA, thank you so much! it relly helped me!

Comment: i have no idea but when tryed your code 20 minutes before nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

you can set the position of the map to absolute and set top, bottom, left and right to 0 and z-index something big.

or you can try and set the map display to block and make sure that the div parent is full screen but hard to confirm as I do not see your css and html.

Comment: The answer is simple. the main issue comes from the PO's knowledge about CSS. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516992/6877799).